# Are there any references for feature extraction using LSTM RNN in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pre-trained-model

Currently I am trying to use pre-trained LSTM RNN model for feature extraction.

I stumbled across following reference for feature extraction using deep neural nets. That's for images however. 
https://www.kernix.com/blog/image-classification-with-a-pre-trained-deep-neural-network_p11

In a similar fashion I would like to use LSTM RNN https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition/? for feature extraction. The code is implemented using Tensorflow BasicLSTMCell.

Is there any way to get the layer like "pool_3:0" as described in the first reference link ?

Any links or references would be helpful.

Comment: Any leads on this ? @Amogh